# convert 32-bit pointer to 64-bit integer

Tags: c

What's the best way to do this?

Say I have:

```
 void* p = 0xc8f68000;
 unsigned long long v = (unsigned long long)p;
```

I got v = 0xffffffffc8f68000 instead of 0x00000000c8f68000. Do I have to use shift?

Comment: If the native integer size is 32 bit, the value `0xc8f68000` is negative... use `0xc8f68000u`

Comment: Try `void* p =0xc8f68000ull;`

Comment: If you want to convert a pointer to an integer (which is questionable in the first place), it's better to convert to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`. If you're doing the conversion so you can print the value, just use `printf` with the `"%p"` format (and cast the pointer value to `(void*)`): `printf("ptr = %p\n", (void*)ptr);`

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you deal with pointer to integer conversions, it's best to use `uintptr_t`.  It is the portable way to avoid size and sign extension issues when casting pointers.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void *p = 0xc8f68000;
uint64_t v = (uintptr_t)p;
```

Comment: Wait, is there a integer type with a similar property? as in it'll take only 8 bits if everything else is all NULL?

OR the other way would work fine too

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that 0xc8f68000 is being treated as a *signed* 32 bit integer, and then being converted to unsigned. You should get the 'correct' value with:

```
void* p = 0xc8f68000;
unsigned long long v = (unsigned long)p;
```

or probably better:

```
void* p = 0xc8f68000;
unsigned long long v = (size_t)p;
```

since the latter isn't dependent on p actually being 32 bits.

I question why you want to do this, however.